# how to create a dataframe loop by adding data to additional data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, api, for-loop

I wanted to extract data from a website using its web API response URL which contains only JSON data but the data consists of thousands of records and the website had limited to show data in the table to only 500 max and it consists of n number of pages.

I used this code it gives the data from the URL  but I am unable to create a single data frame for complete data storage.

```
import pandas as pd
page_no =1
start_value =0
response = 1658837156089
for i in range(2567):
    urltext = 'urllink'.format(page_no=page_no, start_value=start_value, response=response)
    df1=pd.read_json(urltext)
    df2=df1.append(df1, ignore_index=False)
    df1.drop(df1.index,axis=0, inplace=True)
    print(df2)
    page_no+=1
    start_value+=500
    response+=1
```

If you got any idea how I should change please do suggest.

***Additional information***
to get the URL I used this method first I went to the website and locate the data consisting page and started inspecting through inspect mode(ctrl+shift+i) and went to network tab and submitted the request to get data in network tab it creates the API response link I used that to get data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create an empty list at the begining of your code, then append each partial dataframe to it. At the end you concat everything in one dataframe. Would look like

```
import pandas as pd
page_no =1
partial_dfs=[]
start_value =0
response = 1658837156089
for i in range(2567):
    urltext = 'urllink'.format(page_no=page_no, start_value=start_value, response=response)
    df1=pd.read_json(urltext)
    df2=df1.append(df1, ignore_index=False)
    df1.drop(df1.index,axis=0, inplace=True)
    print(df2)
    partial_dfs.append(df2)
    page_no+=1
    start_value+=500
    response+=1
whole_df=pd.concat(partial_dfs)
```

Comment: ```partial_dfs=[]```
 what does it do i tried it but couldn't get any data
if I run the loop with only df1=pd.read_json I do get data but after the iteration it's data is simply gets updated completely

Comment: creating empty list didn't help but creating empty dataframe helped and I edited the empty list line in the code

Answer (score 1):

It is generally slower to append new data to a dataframe in a loop. It is more efficient to extend / append the data to a list and then convert the entire list into a dataframe.

If you absolutely must have the data in pd.DataFrame type, you can have a list of pd.DataFrame and use pd.concat to create one dataframe from a list of dataframes [Refer below].
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html